# ReactJS + Auth0 : Page keeps refreshing after logging in to Auth0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, auth0

I have a good experience in Python but never got a chance to work on the JS frameworks.
Now that I got a project to work on React JS + Auth0, I've been trying to configure these and getting a lot of errors throughout.

I somehow managed to integrate Auth0 in my react application, but now whenever I successfully login to my app using Auth0 authentication, my app keeps refreshing for a couple of seconds and then it throws me back to the Auth0 login screen.

I did search a lot and stumbled across a couple of related posts, but as I mentioned I'm new to React JS, I couldn't utilize those suggestions and so I'm sharing my code for the App.JS down here.

Your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

```
import './App.css';
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react'


function App() {

  const { loginWithRedirect,
    logout,
    isAuthenticated
  } = useAuth0();

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return (
      <div>
        <iframe
          title='My App'

          }}
          class="responsive-iframe"
          src="SOURCE FILE"></iframe>
      </div>
    );
  }

  else if (!isAuthenticated) {
    return (loginWithRedirect())

  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You have to configure the redirect URL in the Auth0 console page. Nothing to do in react about this.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I don't understand, what settings would I need to change on the Auth0 console page?

I have all "Allowed Callback URLs" , "Allowed Logout URLs", and "Allowed Web Origins" defined as the same : http://localhost:3000/